# Image in Canvas in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have this Image in a ScrollViewer (Image is pan- and zoomable):

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="imageScrollViewer" SizeChanged="image_SizeChanged" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="Uniform" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
    MouseMove="image_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown" SizeChanged="image_SizeChanged">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now, I want to draw onto my Image (just some Rectangles for some markings). I guess direct drawing onto the image (without System.Drawing...) is impossible?

I tried using a Canvas (so I can add Rectangle objects) with something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="imageScrollViewer" SizeChanged="image_SizeChanged" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ScrollViewer.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="PageDown" Command="local:MainWindow.NextPage" />
        <KeyBinding Key="PageUp" Command="local:MainWindow.PreviousPage" />
    </ScrollViewer.InputBindings>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
        <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="Uniform" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
    MouseMove="image_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown" SizeChanged="image_SizeChanged">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" />
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now my Image isn't pan- nor zoomable anymore since the canvas "destroys" my whole layout and thus the functionality. In my code-behind I really depend on the Image (and it's ActualWidth/ActualHeight, etc.) since I capture the mouse position and then decide if it's hovered on a marking of the Image.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either a) bind the canvas width/height to the image width/height so that the coordinates are the same, b) use a WritableBitmap and do the drawing onto the actual bitmap.

Comment: I tried your first approach already with no good results. The WriteableBitmap looks good, but wouldn't a DrawingVisual be better for something simple like rectangles? I know how to create and draw with a DrawingContext of a DrawingVisual, but I don't know how I can tell it "take this ImageSource as your base", since I want to edit an already existing ImageSource.

Comment: I've used the first method before with good results. Perhaps you're not transforming the coordinates correctly on mouse down. Per the second, the WritableBitmap is good if you wish to save the bitmap with your drawing stuff already mixed in. Use the DrawingVisual if you wish to keep them separate. And the DrawingVisual has a DrawImage which you'd use first, then the rectangles second.

Comment: I ended up using a DrawingVisual, calling DrawImage first and then drawing the rectangles, which works like a charm and is also pretty fast! Thanks!